# How do I properly gather information from two tables and use them in one controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables named `users` and `billing`. In `users` I have the usual information, while in `billing` (contains `user_id` field for reference) I have things like balances by month for each user. My problem comes from when I want to list the monthly balances. On the monthly balances page I want to display the user(s)'s name, balanace for the month and other misc information, however the `billing` table only holds the user's id.

At first i tried

```
@mondetail = Billings.find_by_date(201204) #April's billing period
@customer = Users.find_by_id(mondetail.user_id)
```

which works fine for one user but how should I go about this when I want to display the information from both tables with multiple users? Or would it just be best for me to add a `user_name` field to the `billing` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need find user's info in controller. You can get it from `Billing` model. (Strange that models are plural)

```
# controller
@mondetail = Billings.includes(:user).find_by_date(201204)


# view
<% @mondetail.each |mondetail| %>
 <%= mondetail.user.name %><br />
 <%= number_to_currency mondetail.balance %>
<% end %>
```

It's will work and without `includes` but you should avoid [N + 1 queries](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) problem